# Migrating from google maps v3 to android maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sdk, migration

We've developed an android app using Google Maps v3, but now we'd like to migrate to Android maps using the SDK. How easy or difficult is it to do so ?

I mean, apart from the SDK installation process, what are other major factors that we have to remember where the structure of Javascript api  v3 would be different with Android Maps SDK?

Lame Question that's stuck in my mind is : By bundling our existing android app code with the SDK, and making references to api, without much changes in the core code, would Android Maps work with very less code change?

Thank you
Sai Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Create /assets/simplemap.html

Paste Your Map Content in that file

like

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 WebView myBrowser;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
  myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/simplemap.html");
  myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 }

}
```